# error in uploading json file on firebase and firebase is not recognizing it

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my project i am uploading json file to firebase which is i want to upload to firebase and  my code of importtofire.json is here :-

```
{
  "SCHOOL NAME" : "Amrit Yatayat school",
  "ADDRESS" : "7'/'2 Chhoti Gawlati Sardar Patel Marg Indore ,Indore '-' 452001",
  "PHONE NO." : "(0731) 2464534"
}
```

In uploading these data i am getting these error :-

```
Invalid JSON data or key values. Key values can’t contain $ # [ ] / or . Learn more
```

Please help me

Comment: Your last key in your JSON contains a . and that isn't allowed: "PHONE NO.". Simply remove it and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code just remove . which you had used and then your error will solve it is here  "PHONE NO." to "PHONE NO"

Answer (score 1):

No changes to your code just save the file as UTF-8 encoding

in SublimeText > File > Save with Encoding > UTF-8

[image]